# Iterate union type in a macro

Tags: crystal-lang

Is there a way to iterate over types in a union type in a macro? Here is my try:

```
alias MyType = Int32 | String

{% for type in MyType.union_types %}  #=> undefined method 'union_types' for TypeNode of type MyType (must be a union type)
  ...
{% end %}
```

I tried to use [TypeNode#union_types](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.22.0/Crystal/Macros/TypeNode.html#union_types%3ACrystal%3A%3AMacros%3A%3AArrayLiteral%28TypeNode%29-instance-method) method, but seems like `MyType` is not considered as a union type at all:

```
{% puts MyType.union? %} #=> false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's currently impossible to use complex alias types in macros. This is a bug, please bump [crystal-lang/crystal#4301](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/4301) with your example.

Answer (score 0):

maybe `typeof` method will help you

```
alias MyType = Int32 | String

puts typeof(MyType) # => (Int32 | String):Class
```

[try here](https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/1ytk)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The idea is to get a list of types at compile time. `typeof` is not available at that point [example](https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/1yvm)